# How can I call a pipe with in a service in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I want to call a pipe with in a service.

just like

```
 export class MyService{

  constructor(private http: Http){}

  getValues(){
    this.http.get(baseUrl).pipe(//pipename) //I want to menton my custom pipe
  }
}
```

After completion of pipe I want to return that observables to component. Is it possible ?

Comment: Please write your question in brief, check spellings, see Stackoverflow documentation.

Comment: Kindly follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call `pipe` in service file like this-

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
class MyService {

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  transformDate(date) {
    this.datePipe.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }
}
```

as you have not provided any example of your use case , I am assuming `DatePipe` here in my example.

## Update

```
export class MyService{

  constructor(private http: Http, private yourPipe: YourPipe){}

  getValues(){
    this.http.get(baseUrl).map(res => {
       return this.yourPipe.transform(res, ----whatever---);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to handle the observable by pipe like `get(){this.http.get().pipe(//pipename)}`  is it possible.?

Comment: Just updated the question. Any idea is it possible or not?

Comment: you want  to use pipe on data return by `http`? if so then try to use same in `.map`

Comment: could you modify your answer?

Comment: Please check Updated answer